# Get-PnPSiteTemplate -Out template.xml -Handlers Lists not getting out the Events list

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, list-template

I have event calendar which has events on it. I want to take this list out and upload it to another site of mine. I wanted to use the `Get-PnPSiteTemplate -Out template.xml -Handlers Lists` to get this list out and then just invoke to add the template to my new site. However the xml extracted has no events list on in. Is this a normal behaviour? I am using SharePoint Online.

Comment: Is there any kind of heavy customization done in "Events" list ?

Comment: Can you try with a `ListsToExtract`  switch like so? `Get-PnPSiteTemplate -Out template.xml -Handlers Lists -ListsToExtract "Event list name"`